# Accessing CollectionView indexPath.row in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I'm trying to access the indexPath.row variable from my collectionView in my prepareForSegue function. I have the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let selectedIndex = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as NSIndexPath
    //let myIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell: LocalFeedCollectionViewCell.self)

    if (segue.identifier == "toFullImage")
    {
        var fullImageVC: FullImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as FullImageViewController
        fullImageVC.imageTitle = self.imageTitles[selectedIndex.row]
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error for selectedIndex - '(UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'indexPathsForSelectedItems'. In Objective-C I see the following solution

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

but I'm not sure how to implement it in swift/if it would work.

Thanks

Comment: I think I may have gotten around the problem by making a variable a variable "var rowPath: Int = 0" and then setting it equal indexPath.row. Then I can write " fullImageVC.imageTitle = self.imageTitles[rowPath]"

Comment: Is the error you have in your question actually generated within that piece of code? I don't see any reference to `numberOfItemsInSection` in the code you provided.

Comment: Yes the error was found on the "let selectedIndex" line

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem is that `indexPathsForSelectedItems()` does not return something that can be cast to an NSIndexPath. It returns an *array*. If you are trying to cast down to an array of index paths, you need to cast down to `[NSIndexPath]`, not to `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: I saw that too, but it didn't seem to match up to the type error in the question. Though, I'm not convinced that type error is actually within that function (since it references `numberOfItemsInSection`).

Comment: It doesn't really matter. There is a compile error on that line, and this is the reason for it. If you try his code and change his `NSIndexPath` to `[NSIndexPath]` the compile error on that line does in fact go away. There may be other problems with his code down the line - I don't know - but this is the answer to that one.

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` parameter is collection view's cell. So first cast it to the `UICollectionViewCell` and then ask indexPath from the collection view. Here is a sample

```
if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell {
    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
        // use indexPath here
    }
}
```